# Could the web service generated with `java2wsdl` include API from more than one Java class?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am using Axis2 to run a web service. Here is a `services.xml` file that defines a service:

```
<service name="XEWS" scope="transportsession" class="com.mc.xews.XEWS">
<messageReceivers>
    <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
    <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
</messageReceivers>
<parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.mc.xews.XEWS</parameter>
```

My problem is that the whole API is located in one single Java file `XEWS.java` and this class is sent to `java2wsdl`. Is there a way to have more than one class as input to `java2wsdl`? This file is used with `WSDL` to generate web service. Right now I use only one class as input to `java2wsdl`, so this class became huge, since there is many API functions.... that could be nicely grouped in separate classes if I knew how to send more than one file to java2wsdl. JavaDocs documentation generated from this class is also hard to read.

Could the web service include API from more than one Java class?

Is maybe `extra classes` option parameter from `java2wsdl` supposed to be used for this?

Comment: Did you try compiling your WSDL with the -u flag?

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling with google... do you have any pointers?

Comment: Where did you find that description? It's incorrect: the `-u` option is short for `--unpack-classes`. You can refer to the [Axis2 WSDL2Java Command Line Tool Documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html) page for more information.

Comment: OK, this option unpacks classes at output of `wsdl2java`. That's nice too, better than one huge `XEWSstub.java` file. But, what I am really looking for is **how to send more than one file into java2wsdl**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible as Axis2 generation tool maps Java class : WSDL as 1:1 in a code-first approach. Hypothetically, they could have provided feature to map multiple Java classes to a single WSDL (that would require additional parameters in generation tool).

Axis2 uses 'extra classes' for additional types - subclasses of original complex types used as input/output.

If neat and compact code is the only issue, I would suggest refactoring it the way that only one single class defines all the required operations, but delegates execution to specific & appropriate (multiple) classes. This can be considered as an application of a [Façade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

In WSDL the largest namespace is the service itself (it's methods are the smallest).  WSDL doesn't support nested namespaces.  The most logical mapping between Java and WSDL is the Java Class to the WSDL Service.  This is what makes your request to pass multiple Java Classes to get a single WSDL impossible.  You can always host more than one WSDL but you still have to generate those separately.

Quoting the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl):

```
Related concrete endpoints are combined into abstract endpoints (services)
```

There is an IMPORT mechanism to combine WSDLs but this is seen as a single service to the WSDL2Java (or any other SOAP client) so the it would still represent a single service.

If you are worried about the size of the implementation, just look at [PayPal's web service](http://www.paypalobjects.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl).